# Escape wildcard (*) in SQL Server Contains function

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

Is there a way to escape the * character in a full text Contains function in sql server 2008? I've tried a standard escape by using square brackets, but that just throws a syntax error. 
Also, any solution can only use full-text functions as the column I'm searching is an image/blob column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in escaping and searching for special characters such as * because they are treated like word separators and are not indexed. Fulltext indexes do not support searching for them.

See also related question [SQL Server Full Text Search Escape Characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995478/sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters)