# Use multiple words in FullText Search input string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have basic stored procedure that performs a full text search against 3 columns in a table by passing in a `@Keyword` parameter. It works fine with one word but falls over when I try pass in more than one word. I'm not sure why. The error says:

Syntax error near 'search item' in the full-text search condition 'this is a search item'

```
SELECT     S.[SeriesID], 
           S.[Name] as 'SeriesName',
           P.[PackageID],
           P.[Name]     
FROM       [Series] S
INNER JOIN [PackageSeries] PS ON S.[SeriesID] = PS.[PackageID]
INNER JOIN [Package]       P  ON PS.[PackageID] = P.[PackageID]
WHERE CONTAINS ((S.[Name],S.[Description], S.[Keywords]),@Keywords)
AND   (S.[IsActive] = 1) AND (P.[IsActive] = 1) 
ORDER BY [Name] ASC
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You will have to do some pre-processing on your @Keyword parameter before passing it into the SQL statement.  SQL expects that keyword searches will be separated by boolean logic or surrounded in quotes.  So, if you are searching for the phrase, it will have to be in quotes:

```
SET @Keyword = '"this is a search item"'
```

If you want to search for all the words then you'll need something like

```
SET @Keyword = '"this" AND "is" AND "a" AND "search" AND "item"'
```

For more information, see the [T-SQL CONTAINS syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187787(v=SQL.90).aspx), looking in particular at the **Examples** section.

As an additional note, be sure to replace the double-quote character (with a space) so you don't mess up your full-text query.  See this question for details on how to do that: [SQL Server Full Text Search Escape Characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995478/sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters)

Comment: Thank you.  Not sure why the MSDN documentation I looked at didn't have this simple, yet extremely common, example.

Comment: @Aaron Is this AND Operator work if use MATCH instead of CONTAINS ? Because I am not getting any output for AND with MATCH condition

Comment: How do we search for phrases that contains " ? do we put double "" or what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Further to Aaron's answer, provided you are using SQL Server 2016 or greater (130), you could use the in-built string fuctions to pre-process your input string. E.g.

```
SELECT
    @QueryString = ISNULL(STRING_AGG('"' + value + '*"', ' AND '), '""')
FROM
    STRING_SPLIT(@Keywords, ' ');
```

Which will produce a query string you can pass to `CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT` that looks like this:

```
'"this*" AND "is*" AND "a*" AND "search*" AND "item*"'
```

or, when `@Keywords` is null:

```
""
```

Answer (score 0):

For those with SQL Server earlier than 2016 you could use the following SQL to format your search query string:

```
    DECLARE @ContentsSearchTerm VARCHAR(500) = REPLACE(@SearchTerm, '"',' ');           
    SET @ContentsSearchTerm = '"' + REPLACE(@ContentsSearchTerm, ' ', '*" AND "') + '*"';
```

Which will produce a query string you can pass to CONTAINS or FREETEXT that looks like this:

```
    '"this*" AND "is*" AND "a*" AND "search*" AND "item*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

### replace % with all space in your text

example : 'Text like this you want to search' ==>
update : 'Text%like%this%you%want%to%search'

Code Example:

```
declare @text as nvarchar(50) = 'test text'
set @text = REPLACE(@text,' ','%')
SELECT TOP (1000) [id]
  ,[value]
  ,[body]
FROM [test].[dbo].[Table_1]
where CONTAINS([body],@text)
```

---

if you want use Full-text Search don't forgot to install that on your mssql