# Regarding sql server table column search with PATINDEX

Tags: sql-server, patindex

i have never use `PATINDEX()` but i hard the table data can be search with `PATINDEX()`.
often i got requirement to search multiple column of any table then i write the sql like

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESS WHERE
((NAME LIKE 'Bill%') OR (CITY LIKE 'Bill%') OR (COMPANY LIKE 'Bill%'))
AND
((NAME LIKE 'Seattle%') OR (CITY LIKE 'Seattle%') OR (COMPANY LIKE 'Seattle%'))
```

**so just tell me the above my sql performance will be good always? i search google to get better sql for searching multiple column of a table and found the below sql**

```
select * from YourTable
WHERE PATINDEX('%text1%',COALESCE(field1,'') + '|' + COALESCE(field2,'') + '|'+ COALESCE(field3,'')+ '|' + COALESCE(field4,'')+ '|' + COALESCE(field9,''))>0
AND
 PATINDEX('%text2%',COALESCE(field1,'') + '|' + COALESCE(field2,'') + '|'+ COALESCE(field3,'')+ '|' + COALESCE(field4,'')+ '|' +COALESCE(field9,''))>0
```

please guide me that the above sql `PATINDEX` syntax is ok for searching multiple column. if not then guide me how can i use the `PATINDEX` function to search multiple column with multiple value. thanks

### UPDATE QS

you gave a link and that show me how to search multiple fields with multiple keyword. here it is

```
SELECT FT_TBL.ProductDescriptionID,
   FT_TBL.Description, 
   KEY_TBL.RANK
FROM Production.ProductDescription AS FT_TBL INNER JOIN
   CONTAINSTABLE (Production.ProductDescription,
      Description, 
      '(light NEAR aluminum) OR
      (lightweight NEAR aluminum)'
   ) AS KEY_TBL
   ON FT_TBL.ProductDescriptionID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
WHERE KEY_TBL.RANK > 2
ORDER BY KEY_TBL.RANK DESC;
GO
```

but the problem is it is bit complicated to understand. can u give me sql for searching multiple fields with multiple keywords with full text search.

can i write something like this for searching multiple fields against multiple value

```
SELECT Title
FROM Production.Document
WHERE FREETEXT (Document, '(vital) OR (safety) OR (components)')

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS((ProductName, ProductNumber, Color), 
'(vital) OR (safety) OR (components)');
```

`what is the difference between FREETEXT and CONTAINS ?? can u please explain.`

thanks

Comment: Why would the `City` column contain "Bill" or the `NAME` column contain Seattle? Are you always searching for columns starting with a string as in your first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for fast search multiple columns you can setup [Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) on sql server
then your queries will look like that

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESS 
WHERE Contains((name, city, company), 'Bill') and Contains(*, 'Seattle')
```

**EDIT**

Syntax of full-text search queries described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)

**EDIT**

you can write

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CONTAINS((ProductName, ProductNumber, Color), 
'"vital" OR "safety" OR "components"');
```

rows that contains any of words in any searched column are returned. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441775/use-multiple-words-in-fulltext-search-input-string) answer

for difference between contains and freetext check [Sql Server Full-Text Search Protips Part 2: CONTAINS vs. FREETEXT](http://www.sitepoint.com/sql-server-full-text-search-protips-part-2-contains-vs-freetext/) article

Comment: i just do not understand ur query. r u trying to say Bill against name,city,company and what is the meaning of Contains(*, 'Seattle') ??

Comment: also tell me how could supply multiple keyword for searching across multiple fields in Full-Text Search ??

Comment: @Thomas, assuming you have set up only columns name, city, company to be indexed for full-text search, `Contains((name, city, company), 'Bill')` and `Contains(*, 'Bill')` give you same results. That expressions evaluates to `true` if any of column value have a substring Bill. And yes it is possible to search for multiple keywords over multiple columns. See link in answer and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx)