# Implement full text search for searching multiple Keywords

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have implemented full-Text search in my application for searching a keyword from a table in my database.Now i want to extend the search for multiple words.I googled for it but didnt get the answer i wanted.Can anyone tell how to extend the search for multiple keywords.

**Query**:

```
select ProductCode,CategorySequenceNumber from tblProductMaster where Contains(*,@stringToSearch)
```

Any suggessions will be appriciated..

Comment: I don't understand you question. Where do you need help ? On making a field in a form to enter multiple keywords ?

Comment: @LukeMarlin i want the query to implement it.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441775/use-multiple-words-in-fulltext-search-input-string

Comment: @LukeMarlin your answer is k.but tell how can i modify the above query ..

Comment: You don't have to modify it. You simply need to change the parameter you put in your query.

Comment: I tried to modify as this  select ProductCode,CategorySequenceNumber from tblProductMaster
where Contains(*, '@stringToSearch OR @stringToSearch1' ) but it gives me an error "Incorrect syntax near keyword OR"

Comment: As I said, you don't need to modify your query. You just need to modify the `@stringToSearch` parameter. So `@stringToSearch` must contain an aggregate of your words

Answer (score 2):

Pass in your keywords separated by "AND" or "OR" depending on the behavior you want :

```
SET @stringtosearch = '"this" AND "word" OR "test"'
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also don't forget to watch out for stop words such as someone looking for "this is a test" if you just `Replace " " with " AND "` you're going to have `"this AND is AND a AND test"` which will return 0 results due to `stop words`. To solve that there's plenty of answers on SO and in search engines.

Comment: @Seph I know Luke's answer is correct.But i need to modify the above  query(given in question) so that if i enter multiple woprds in a textbox it ca search and give me some results.And my question is in sqlserver and not in tsql.

Comment: Wether it is simple SQL or TSQL, you just have to change the parameter by giving it your words, separated by a boolean operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the search text at spaces to a string array and then search for each of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use FREETEXT function intead of CONTAINS. seperate your keywords with spaces.