# SQL Server 2016, How to use CONTAINS() with multiple word search of database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

New to SQL for the most part so perhaps there is a better approach but I'm looking for a way to search through a database using a textbox which can take any number of words/numbers. Basically like a search engine.
Columns to be searched: `[Col1], [Col2], and [Col3]`

I have the table Full-Text indexed, is there a way I can use `CONTAINS` for this?

```
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(500)
SET @Search = 'foo 7 bar' -- can have multiple words/numbers

SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE CONTAINS([Col1] or [Col2] or [Col3], @Search)
```

I realize the last line syntax is incorrect but that's basically what I'm looking for. Shouldn't be exact match or case sensitive, nor should the order of wording matter `('red cat' = 'cat red')`. Also would like to show results for close matches, i.e., some of the keywords don't match anything.

Thank you!

Comment: This should give you hint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441775/use-multiple-words-in-fulltext-search-input-string

Answer (score 1):

Your each search word must be surrounded in quotes..

```
'"Hi" AND "I" AND "am" AND "Yogeesha"'
```

For more information, Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187787(v=SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, using `FREETEXT()` gives a close result to what I've been looking for.