# Searching a full-text indexed column for pipe characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

Consider a column names `MyCol` with a full-text index. We want to find those rows that have a value of `|foo|`.

Tried this, but doesn't find those with *exactly* `|foo|`:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(MyCol,'"|foo|"')
```

It returns anything with `foo`. It seems as if pipes are disregarded as separators.

How can I escape, or otherwise ensure that the exact string `|foo|` is found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape with:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(MyCol,'[|]foo[|]')
```

I think this works too:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE CONTAINS(MyCol,'||foo||') ESCAPE '|'
```

---

Oops, this is full-text search. According to this question/answer, **there is no way!**:

**[sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995478/sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters)**