# Full text index and parametrized query with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, full-text-search

I've got a query builder that's been built in house which is using a full text index in order to perform description searches.

The query is built and parametrized and I was wondering the best way to encode the form field from the website in order to pass search strings such as:

1. Covered by
2. "red" near "yellow"
3. red" fish

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to encode parameters values to avoid SQL injection and to support special chars at the same time? what type are the input parameters of your stored proc?

Comment: It's not using a stored procedure it's a parametrized query, so the query looks like Select x from y where q = @param1. I want to be able to expose the power of the full text index to the users. So they can say give me everything that has "RED" near "Shirt" for example.

Comment: The parameter type in this instance is string, sorry forgot to mention in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use full text search you should use where clause with other specific functions ( not just = or like ).

@param1 will still be a string (nvarchar eventually); see here:

[Querying SQL Server Using Full-Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142559.aspx)

for example, you query in this way (from MSDN):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
DECLARE @SearchWord nvarchar(30)
SET @SearchWord = N'performance'
SELECT Description 
FROM Production.ProductDescription 
WHERE CONTAINS(Description, @SearchWord);
```

about special chars and escaping them, just have a look here: [SQL Server Full Text Search Escape Characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995478/sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing, but passing the above examples doesn't work.

Comment: Show your SQL, this: Select x from y where q = @param1 does not work, does not use full text at all... where is the CONTAINS? how do you execute the query?

Comment: Sorry that wasn't a good example I've now solved it using a microsoft article. However the article to full text search characters has solved the issue.