# Search "Our" Use Full Text Search with Contains in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

We Use Full text search and `Contains` to search between records in SQL Server 2008 R2, here are the samples:

```
NEWS(Title): "We", "New", "Our", "Long-Term", "Seem", "Non.Active"
```

So as you see in the `News` table the title field have the values.
We can search all of the values except  `"Long-Term" And "Non.Active"`, actually we can not search the words includes dash("-") or dot("."). We also check these tips:

```
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'Non.Active');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'Non Active');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'NonActive');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'Non*');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'Active');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'Non');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, '*Active');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "Non.Active" ');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "Non Active" ');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "NonActive" ');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "Non*" ');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "*Active" ');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "Active" ');
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "Non" ');
```

But none of them return any result.
Also we rebuild Full Text Index and yet we did not get any result.

So the question is: Is there any way to search the words include "." or "-" with full text `Contains` predicate? any suggestion

**UPDATE**

I'm really sorry the main problem is another?

you all right about two words of "non" and "Action". but the main case I test it is "We.Our" and steel not return any result? That's so wired, I test "Non.Action" with above search and worked but "We.Our" don't. So I try another record, I inserted the "our" and the search result is yet null. The problem is about "**Our**" word? what is the problem with "**our**" I also check it in SQL Server 2012, and not worked also. is there any one have any idea about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Full Text Search Escape Characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995478/sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters)

Comment: @RGraham The Answer you mentioned Not worked for me. The samples contains "{" or """ returned result in my search also. but how about "." or "-"?

Comment: The point of that answer is that SQL ignores all special characters and treats this as two words: *non* and *active*.

Comment: @RGraham if your answer is correct, the `SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, ' "Non" ');` Or `SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title, 'Non');` must return value, but not.

Comment: @RGraham your right, I am sorry, I update the question

Answer (score 0):

In My cases, it simply works as

```
SELECT * FROM NEWS WHERE  Contains(Title,'"Non.*"');
```

But i hear there is little bug in 2008 version.May the problem will solve after updating sql server instances.

Comment: Sorry for asking, Have u used "our" keyword as a work breaker or not  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check how needed data is stored in Fulltext catalog:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document(db_id('DBname'), object_id('TableName'))
WHERE document_id = <Unique Id>
```

What about the "our" word, it seems to be a stop-word.

Answer (score 0):

The point is the Block words and Noisy words should be checked, in my case the `our` was a noisy word, I don't know why. but the problem solved