# SQL like query on field containing wild cards

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server table called AAA I have field called BBB containing strings full of wild cards:

*&abc##v*

_&abc##&&

_&abc##_12

_&abc##%

I need to allow user to search for partial matches on this field.
User's search phrase will contain lots of wild cards.
What is the best approach for this problem?

I guess I could write something like:

```
select * from AAA where BBB like '%' + 
(add escape character to every wild card found in user's question) + '%' 
escape 'whatever char is not being used in user's question'
```

But I do not like this idea.  Is there any better one?

Comment: can you explain why you don't like the approach you have?  Seems like a pretty sensible way to go about it.

Comment: It would work but seems to me as something too complicated.

Comment: There's not much complicated about this.  Pretty standard that certain characters need to be escaped depending upon how they are processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OR you can make use of Full-text Search which gives you way better performance as compare to LIKE operator,I would Create full-text indexes the tables and make use of full-text search

```
DECLARE @userValue nvarchar(100) = 'some Value'
Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = '''''select * from myTable
WHERE CONTAINS (myColumn, "' + @userValue + '")'''''

EXECUTE sp_Executesql @sql
```

Comment: Disagree on the "way better performance" part.  Having extensively used full text search this is rarely true.

Comment: Also FTS treats special characters as word delimiters and as such they won't appear in an index unless you go so far as to redefine those delimiters.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995478/sql-server-full-text-search-escape-characters

Comment: so some extent you are right. but in some cases it does work better then LIKE operator. depends on what kind of query you are executing. In my personal experience I did gain way better performance using full-text search and returned only the results I actually needed making use of FORMSOF, Inflectional and thesaurus filters in FTS.

Comment: Well, that's why it exists: difference systems, different behavior.  Either way, the answer won't help the OP due to issues with escaped characters and FTS.

Comment: In this particular case when you have data like this '_&abc##&&' user will be searching for some human readable data not special characters, I think FTS will work better in this case.

Comment: You must have missed this in the OP: "User's search phrase will contain lots of wild cards." clearly they are searching for those characters.