# How do I escape parenthesis within a CONTAINS using T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, escaping, contains

I want to have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE
CONTAINS (MyField, '(429)')
```

The problem, is that the parenthesis are ignored and it is finding anything with "429".  I just want "(429)" found.  If I change it to have '"(429)"' that does not help (it still returns items with just "429").

Comment: Maybe it's a noise word?

Comment: Good idea, but if it is a noise word, wouldn't it return no results? I am getting too many results.

Comment: Parentheses are used to change the order of evaluation of logical operators.  Even though you are not using logical, SQL Server is interpreting "(429)" as a parenthesized group and thus only using the "429"

Comment: So is it also finding '(429)'.   If so I suspect FULLTEXT is parsing out the 429 and (  ) are just separators that are thrown out.

Comment: It seems there is a similar question ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/995478/2523686)). Also, check this ([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1d27b9eb-9921-4d80-bd43-4b318964dc22/fulltext-search-with-symbols-?forum=transactsql))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should explicitly convert (429) to a varchar.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a16434f3-5b94-44a1-a8cf-d66f832e1195/convert-integer-to-string

Comment: Thanks @El Hombre (yes, I know who you are).  I'll have to give that a shot.

Comment: (replace _at_ with an at sign below - silly stack overflow) I'm trying this but getting zero results.  Very odd.  I'm just doing DECLARE _at_MyVar VARCHAR followed by SET _at_MyVar = '(429)' and then replacing the second parameter of the CONTAINS function in my query to _at_MyVar and am getting zero results.  I have tried using NVARCHAR, setting the variable to N'(429)' or '429' or N'429' with zero results as well.  I must be missing something simple.